# Bypass objects in the way - flash and actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I have a virtual world, players walking in the world space.

but, i have one problem:
In the map, i have objects(bushes, trees and more..), And I want that once a player clicks anywhere on the map("target"), he gets there after that he bypass all the objects.

Embodiment:
http://s4.uploads.im/t/16TcC.png

Thank!

Comment: What have you tried? what's your existing code?  As is, your question is too broad.

Comment: Have you researched pathfinding algorithms? I'll warn you now that this isn't a trivial task. Probably the most common algorithm is A*, which has a tonne of AS3-based tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that's what you want, but seems like you're looking for a path finder.

This should help you: https://code.google.com/p/as3pathfinder/

Comment: This is a very low quality answer. Consider giving an actual example instead of just a link. At the very least an overview of what your answer is going to accomplish would be nice.